# Which heroes interact with Bastion?

Tags: overwatch

Maybe it's just that not a lot of people play Bastion on console, probably due to the prevalence of Pharahs and Pro Genjis, but I don't think I've ever heard any of the cast interact with Bastion in the pre-match banter.

Which characters interact with Bastion, and what do they say?

Comment: Also, why downvotes with no explanation? This isn't open-ended, there's a finite list, it's not opinion based...?

Comment: If one didn't read the body closely, one might assume from the title that you're asking which characters synergize well with Bastion from a gameplay perspective, which would probably attract downvotes.

Comment: Downvotes can be for lack of research effort or if people feel a question is not useful, which is naturally subjective. Or they might just dislike the question. The guidelines for downvotes are just that: guidelines.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Summing together [this wiki page](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Bastion/Quotes) *(which I've now updated to reflect this answer)*, [this reddit list](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4feyw0/character_interaction_master_post/), and [@MageXY's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283816/which-heroes-interact-with-bastion/283817#283817) *(which I've verified from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKsinUf3CNQ#t=0m40s))*, I've found six characters that interact with Bastion: Lucio, Mei, Zarya, Zenyatta, Reaper, and Torbjorn:

> **Lúcio:** Hey, Bastion! *imitates beeping*
>   **Mei:** Bastion? You will make the perfect research assistant.
>   **Zarya:** I have destroyed more of your kind than you want to know.
>   **Zenyatta:** Tell me your thoughts, my friend.
>   **Reaper:** *(When killing enemy Bastion or Zenyatta)* Tin cans: Dime a dozen.
>   **Torbjorn:** I hate working with these talking tin cans!

Comment: While I appreciate the list, I did find this Wiki page, and it is marked as a stub. I don't believe it's the full list, as it doesn't include the dialogue that Mage Xy included.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: Well, it is a wiki.  If you know of any lines that are missing, please add them!

Comment: These are the only ones I can find, plus the one Mage Xy said, which I don't see anywhere else and can't specifically recall hearing.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: I found a reference to support MageXY's claim, and updated both my answer and the wiki.

Comment: Good old [citogenesis](https://xkcd.com/978/)!

Comment: Torbjorn says the line at :40. He's probably talking about Bastion, but he might just be commenting on the map, which is a city where robots and humans live in peace. A lot of the characters comment on maps. I'm suspicious that's the case since they're way out of the spawn area by the time he says it.

Comment: @DCShannon: Bastion immediately responds with beep-boops _(like he does with other characters)_, so it's clearly a dialogue between them.

Comment: Lúcio imitating Bastions beeps is the funniest quote.

Answer (score 4):

I only remember one interaction. If you have both a Bastion and a Torbjorn on the team, the Torbjorn will make a remark about his disgust for working with "talking tin cans", to which Bastion will reply with a sad boop.